# Filter value inside array in MongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm trying to filter some records in MongoDb but the problem is that I have this information inside an array.

For example:

```
...
...

"Docs" : {
    "1234567890" : {
        "One" : 1,
        "Two" : true,
        "Three" : 1711
    }
}
...
...
```

I want to search all records that have "1234567890" inside "Docs".

How do I do that?

What I'm trying:

```
"Docs.1234567890": { $exists: true }
```

And:

```
"Docs": { $in: ["1234567890"] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your first attempt is correct and that worked when I tried it.

Comment: Actually I don't know if it's working because it's taking so much time to finish =/ ...is there anything faster? Guess this is inefficient..